# General SQL - Understanding Group BY

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, average

Im having some troubles understanding GROUP BY.

1. Does every expression in the SELECT statement other then the Aggregate Function have to be in the GROUP BY?
2. What exactly is GROUP BY doing?

Im trying to calculate the Average Age of our Clients.

```
Date| Name|Country|Balance|Age
2016|Sharp|Iceland|  $200 |29 
2016|Bob  |Finland|  $100 |22 
2016|Sharp|Iceland|  $500 |29
2016|James|USA    |   $10 |21 
2017|Sharp|Iceland|    $2 |30
```

Because the data is very large, I do a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT Date, Name, Country, SUM(Balance), Age 
  FROM Table 
 GROUP BY Date, Name, Country, Age
```

However, what would be the output of this...would it be:

```
2016|Sharp|Iceland|$700|29
2016|Bob  |Finland|$100|22
2016|James|USA    |$10 |21
2017|Sharp|Iceland|$700|30
```

How would I go about calculating the Average Age then?

So confused,
Sharp.

Answer (score 1):

**Does every expression in the SELECT statement other then the Aggregate Function have to be in the GROUP BY?**

- .. Every expression mentioned in select must be either in group by
     clause or any aggregate function must be applied on it. But vice
     versa i.e. every expression in group by need not to be in select.

**What exactly is GROUP BY doing?**

- group by, arranges data as per group by clause and apply aggregate
  function on column which is used in aggregate function.

In your example , as you said , you need to average of Age but what should be the criteria for group by clause? Do you want average Age date wise , country wise , or date wise and country wise both ..

Below are sample queries:

```
-- date and contry wise both 
select Country,Avg(Age) from demo123
group by Date,Country

-- date wise 
select Date,Avg(Age) from demo123
group by Date 

-- Country wise 
select Country,Avg(Age) from demo123
group by Country
```

Comment: I would need it by total number of clients. Could I do SELECT Date,Count(*) As Total_Accounts, AVG(Age) FROM Table GROUP BY Date

Answer (score 0):

I am completely new to SQL and programming in general but from what I've learned so far:

GROUP BY takes multiple columns from a database and condenses them to one group to be sortered. The synatax would be as follows:
SELECT column name(s)
FROM table
WHERE condition needed (AVG age)
GROUP BY column names

You could then order them if you wanted. I believe you are correct in saying that if you select the column you will group by the same columns you have selected.

This is a reference I've used. [SQL info](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

It doesn't go into too much depth, but this is how I read it.

Hope something I said might help. Best of luck.

Sprout

Answer (score 0):

The `Aggregate` Functions returns the output based on the `Select` list and that selected columns must be in `GROUP BY` clause.

Your required Query would be like this.

```
SELECT Date, Name, Country, SUM(Balance), AVG(Age) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Date, Name, Country
```